# Twin Lightswitch wiring - uk

Tags: switch, light

Earlier today my kitchen light switch fell apart.
I picked up a replacement and weird it as best I could comparing the terminals on the old switch

The kitchen has two lights on a 2 gang switch. Now one of the lights is on and off I flip one of the switches it goes out and the other comes on. Second switch does nothing.

There is a red wire, grey, blue & yellow plus a red common wire that was bridged between the two common terminals.

Edit picture added
[image]

Comment: Turn the power to the lights off, open up the box and take clear, focused pictures of all the switches showing the wiring from the switch and all the way into the box. [Edit] those into your question.

Comment: Will do. I'm going to leave it for tonight though and pick it up in the morning so I can see what I'm doing.

Comment: Looking at the old switch that fell to bits. Grey wire was A 2 way, red was A 1 way. The red wire that was bridged was common a & blue was B 2 way & yellow was B 1 way.  The new switch is an mk logic with 2 distinct switch blocks. The only one that's marked on each switch is the com.  I'll get the picture of the new switch in the morning.